Connected graph and set of transpositions?
Let us consider $\mathfrak{S}_n$ the group of permutations and $\mathfrak{T}_n$ the set of transpositions of $\mathfrak{S}_n$.
We define for every $T \subset \mathfrak{T}_n$ subset of transpositions, the graph  $G_T=(\{1,\dots n\}, T)$ where $ij$ is an edge of $G_T$ iff $(i \  j)\in T$.
I meet some difficulties to prove that : if $\langle T \rangle = \mathfrak{S}_n$ then $G_T$ is connected.
I consider first the following equivalence relation on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ : $i \equiv_T j$ iff there exists a path from $i$ to $j$ in $G_T$ and then define $C_{G_T}:= {\{1,\dots,n\}}/_{\equiv_T}$ the connected components of the graph $G_T$.
I noticed that for any transposition $\tau_{i,j}\in T$, $\tau_{i,j}(C_{G_T}) \subseteq C_{G_T}$. Indeed, if $i$ and $j$ are both in the same connected component, then as $\tau_{i,j}$ exchanges $i$ and $j$ and stabilizes the other "vertices", the connected component is the same. Also if $i$ and $j$ are not in the connected component then for every $k \neq i \ \text{and} \ j$, $\tau_{i,j}(k)=k$ and the connected component remains the same. Hence for every connected components $\tau_{i,j}(C_{G_T}) \subseteq C_{G_T}$.
Now as $\langle T \rangle = \mathfrak{S}_n$, then each $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions of $T$. However as mentioned previously, every connected components of $G_T$ is stable by each element of $T$. Hence every connected components is stable by every $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$. From this fact how can I conclude that there is only one connected component in $G_T$ ?
Thanks in advance !

Can you try and prove the contrapositive? Suppose $G_T$ is not connected; what can you say about $\langle T\rangle$?

A geometrical understanding is brought by the permutohedron representation

@SteveD if $G_T$ is not connected then there exists $i\neq j \in {1,\dots,n}$ s.t there is no path joining $i$ to $j$, hence the vertices $i$ and $j$ belong to two different connected components. In particular the transposition $(i\ j)\not \in T$.

It's even more than that right? There's no path from $i$ to $j$, so can $\langle T\rangle$ be all of $S_n$?

@SteveD I'd say that in particular there exists a finite number of index $l \in {1, \dots,n}$ s.t : $(a_{l-1} \ a_{l})\not \in T$ (with convention $a_0 = i, \ a_l=j$). The product of all those transpositions gives an element of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ which is not in $\langle T \rangle$

Even stronger, no element in $\langle T\rangle$ can send $i$ to $j$.

@SteveD Ok I see, hence the transposition $(i \ j)$ cannot be generated by elements of $T$. Consequently, in this case $\langle T \rangle \neq  \mathfrak{S}_n$

Hint: Use $\sigma = (1 2 \cdots n)$
EDIT: For those who hastily deleted this answer without taking the time to read OP's progress, observe that they have rightfully deduced that the connected components of $G_T$ are stabilized by every $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$. My hint was to use the specific permutation $\sigma$ suggested above in order to prove that the graph $G_T$ is connected.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

So with this remark, we obtain that in particular the connected components of $G_T$ are stabilized by the $n$-cycle $(1 \ 2 \dots \ n)$. Hence each connected component contains all the vertices of $G_T$ and then the only possibility is that $G_T$ has exactly one connected component ?

Yep, that's right!
